# Decorators: how arguments are passed to wrapped function?

Tags: python, decorator

I have following decorator example

```
def makeitalic(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):     
       return "<I>" + f(args[0]) + "</I>"
    return wrapped

def myprint(text):
    return text


myprint = makeitalic(myprint)
print myprint('hii')
```

---

```
Output:
<I>hii</I>
```

How does the wrapped function (inner function) get the arguments of the original function?

Comment: No other resources. Just read this [How can I make a chain of function decorators in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/1903116)

Comment: `myprint` is the inner function, so they're passed explicitly by you with: `('hii')`, and forwarded with `f(args[0])`.

Comment: Nice ! both helped me. actually I am getting wrapped function object. myprint = makeitalic(myprint). What I am doing is calling wrapped. Is it correct?

Comment: decorators are basically syntactic sugar for what you're actually doing. For the decorator syntax you would delete the line `myprint = makeitalic(myprint)`, but then add `@makeitalic` above the `def`.

Comment: Are you confusing about how wrapped received the argument *args or how the makeitalic received func 'myprint', which part you are confusing, i hope i can try to explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapped function *doesn't* get the arguments of the original function. It gets arguments that it can (and usually does) choose to pass on to the original function.

When you do `myprint = makeitalic(myprint)`, the name `myprint` now refers to the wrapped function. It no longer refers to the function defined earlier as `myprint`.

So, when you call `myprint('hii')`, you are calling the wrapped function. The original function has no arguments yet because it has never been called.

Inside `wrapped`, you make a call to `f`. This is the original function, and you pass it `args[0]`, which is `'hii'`. So, now the original function is called. It gets the first argument of the wrapped function, because that's what you chose to pass it.

Answer (score -1):

thefourtheye already linked to the full explanation, so here's the shortest explanation that could possibly answer your question: the `(*args, **kwargs)` represents all arguments passed to the `wrapped` function. `args` is a tuple and `kwargs` is a dictionary. So when the `wrapped` function references `args[0]`, it means "the first argument that was passed.